Font displayed as squares in bluemail app in Ubuntu 20.04
I have installed Bluemail, and it works flawlessly in Ubuntu 20.04. However, whenever I try to print a mail, it shows the print dialogue box, and all the fonts are shown as squares.
Fonts displayed incorrectly in dialogue box
I have looked at the following answers, and it didn't work for me.
answer 1
and this too.
answer 2
Can someone point out in the right direction?

I fixed this problem by removing fontconfig from
~/snap/bluemail/common/.cache and then installing sudo apt install fonts-ubuntu-classic after reboot, in bluemail dialogue box font is normal
